# Get all the children of parents MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I have a sample MySQL table with the columns **ID, NAME** AND **ID_PARENT**.

| ID | NAME | ID_PARENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NODE 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NODE 2 | 1 |
| 3 | NODE 3 | 7 |
| 4 | NODE 4 | 2 |
| 5 | NODE 5 | 10 |
| 6 | NODE 6 | 5 |
| 7 | NODE 7 | 5 |
| 8 | NODE 8 | 7 |
| 9 | NODE 9 | 6 |
| 10 | NODE 10 | 1 |
| 11 | NODE 11 | NULL |
| 12 | NODE 12 | 11 |
| 13 | NODE 13 | 14 |
| 14 | NODE 14 | 10 |
| 18 | NODE 15 | 14 |

If I want to get the children of Node 1 then I will get the following.

```
     NODE 1
    /      \
NODE 2     NODE 10
  |          |
NODE 4       |__________________
             |                 |
           NODE 5              |
            /   \              |
       NODE 6   NODE 7       NODE 14
         |         |        /     \
       NODE 9   NODE 3  NODE 15   NODE 13
```

**If you think why the NODE 7 is the parent of NODE 3. The answer is that we can modify parents after the creation of all nodes.**

I am using the following SQL query and it cannot get all the nodes. But, if the id_parent data is in asc order within the table then it works fine.

```
SELECT id,
       node_name,
       id_parent
FROM   tree
WHERE  id=1
UNION
SELECT id,
       node_name,
       id_parent
FROM   (
                SELECT   id,
                         node_name,
                         id_parent
                FROM     tree t
                ORDER BY t.id_parent ) tree,
       (
              SELECT @pv := 1) initialisation
WHERE  Find_in_set(id_parent, @pv) > 0
AND    @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id);
```

By running the above SQL I get the following nodes.

```
     NODE 1
    /      \
NODE 2     NODE 10
  |          |
NODE 4       |___________
             |          |
           NODE 5       |
                        |
                      NODE 14
                      /     \
                  NODE 15   NODE 13
```

So, how can I modify the query so that I get all the nodes as demonstrated in the first NODES representation?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySQL 8.0 supports [recursive CTE queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). That's the preferred solution, and it's worth upgrading to 8.0 if you have not done so. But if you must use an earlier version of MySQL, see my answer to [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/20860) or my presentation [Models for hierarchical data](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few 'models' of storing the hierarchical data in relational model, each with it's own pros and cons.

The model you've presented (the adjacency list) is the easiest to understand, but also the most limiting.

This article offers a great overview of viable solutions https://www.databasestar.com/hierarchical-data-sql/ so you can weight the adequacy of each approach to your requirements.